# Como hacer dos LEFT JOIN hacia una misma tabla con el mismo identificador (SQL)

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

tengo un problema a la hora de realizar una consulta a una base de datos sql.

Resumidamente la base de datos que tengo es así:

```
CREATE TABLE users(
 id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
 username VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE posts(
 id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
 user1 INT,
 user2 INT,
 FOREIGN KEY fk_user1(user1) REFERENCES users(id),
 FOREIGN KEY fk_user2(user2) REFERENCES users(id)
);

INSERT INTO users VALUES
(1,'juan'),
(2,'root');

INSERT INTO posts VALUES
(null,1,2);
```

Y el objetivo es que con una consulta devuelva lo siguiente:

| id | user1 | username1 | user2 | username2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | juan | 2 | root |

Comment: Si lo que buscas es `CreadoPor` y `ModificadoPor`, la respuesta de Guido no te servirá. Si tienes un post que ha sido creado pero no modificado, la consulta no lo devolverá. Tienes que usar `LEFT JOIN` en lugar de `JOIN`

Comment: cierto, no lo había comprobado, me acabas de una hehe, gracias :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select p.id, p.user1, U1.username, p.user2, U2.username from posts P
join users U1 on P.user1 = U1.id
join users U2 on P.user2 = U2.id;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/86e18f/5

Comment: Muchas gracias era justo lo que buscaba, me has ayudado mucho.

Comment: Qué pasa si User2 es null? La consulta no devuelve ningún registro.